# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 "Runtime error occurred while mediating the message"

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 to call an API endpoint. The API endpoint is:

https://mornpen.crisisworks.com/api/json/item?token=(my_token)&uuid=(my_uuid)

The payload of values sent is in JSON format. It is:

{ "itemSchemaName":"mornPen", "type" : "fpn", "assetId" : "1289477", "eventId" : "1057", "status" : "10", "externalId" : "883647", "assignee" : "2806" }

ESB is able to make the API call but right after that, it throws a runtime error message: **Runtime error occurred while mediating the message. java.lang.NullPointerException**.

Any idea what the issue could be?

The error stacktrace is below:

ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Runtime error occurred while mediating the message {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseJsonPath.stringValueOf(SynapseJsonPath.java:75)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorProperty.getEvaluatedExpression(MediatorProperty.java:138)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.setCustomProperties(LogMediator.java:223)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getSimpleLogMessage(LogMediator.java:168)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getLogMessage(LogMediator.java:134)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.mediate(LogMediator.java:101)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.Target.mediate(Target.java:109)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:176)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:200)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you add the error stacktrace

Comment: I have updated the description with the error stacktrace.

Comment: It seems that the issue occurs within a log mediator while extracting values from a property. Could you attach the synapse configurations as well